# Angular function with delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi want to perform the applyParameters function after a 5 second delay. However my current syntax isn't doing it.

Any idea about how to do this?

```
//Add and update categories
                var categories = homeData['categories'];
                for(var catIndex in categories){
                    var category = categories[catIndex];
                    $scope.addCategory(category);
                }

                $scope.search.text = homeData['keyword'];

                //Pick first company in the results
                $scope.updateSelectedCompany( response.data[0] );

                //populate parameters if passed in after 1 second delay
                $timeout($scope.applyParameters($routeParams.param1), 5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code in a function:

```
$timeout(function(){
     $scope.applyParameters($routeParams.param1);
}, 5000);
```

Currently `$scope.applyParameters($routeParams.param1)` is evaluated and Angular tries to call the return value of `applyParameters` as a function.